# "xmlResult.Result is undefined" error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i make a simple script of php which get city name by postal code using ajax
my java code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-xml2json-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var initialPostal;
            $('#postal').bind('keyup change',function(e) {
            if(($("#postal").val().length==3 || $("#postal").val().length==6 || $("#postal").val().length==7) && $("#postal").val()!=initialPostal)
                { 
                              initialPostal=$("#postal").val();
                        $.get('citylookup.php?postal='+$("#postal").val(), function(xml){
                        var xmlResult = $.xml2json(xml);
                            $("#city").val(xmlResult.Result.City);
                            alert(xmlResult.Result.City);
                        }); } });   });  </script>
```

//this is my html code

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Postal:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

and my citylookup.php page code is hear

```
<?php
$url = 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q='.$_GET['postal'].'&country=india';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml as $result)
{
    if($result->postal==$_GET['postal'])
    {
    $City = $result->city;
    }

}
echo $City;
?>
```

it gives me a error like

```
Error: xmlResult.Result is undefined
Source File: http://localhost/postalcode/citylookup.html
Line: 17
```

any solution ?

Comment: Alert / console.log the  `xmlResult` on the line before ... im pretty sure that will help you resolve your problem ...

Comment: "Alert / console.log the xmlResult on the line before" this solution is not working

Comment: If wasn't meant to provide a solution - it was meant to assist you .... i suggest looking at a tool called [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) ...

Comment: Ive just been playing around with this for a UK post code and it works - but if i enter my postcode with a space the lookup still works but the postcode returned by yahoo doesnt match the postcode entered ... beware of that too ...

Comment: i need to post a indian postal code like 363641, 382721
see citylookup.php in $url i mention a county "India"

Comment: I suggest you use firebug - what your are returning using your PHP is a single word - not XML / JSON ....

Comment: Did you resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that the `$City` variable isnt declared before the `foreach` block - so you will get an error there ...

> ```
> <br /> <b>Notice</b>:  
> Undefined variable: City in <b>citylookup.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
> ```

try :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q='.$_GET['postal'].'&country=india';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$City = "";
foreach($xml as $result)
{
    if($result->postal==$_GET['postal'])
    {
    $City = $result->city;
    }

}
echo $City;
?>
```

Your second problem is that there is no error checking in your JavaScript - ie if you type in an unknown postal you will see the same error - think about checking the return value to ensure there is actually something valuable returned. You are actually just returning a single word using the above PHP ... not XML / JSON